# MySQL connection string using password

Tags: mysql, connections

I am creating app with ExpressJS and want to use MySQL with password, but I have problem with connection string

`mysql://user@localhost:3306/db`

in this string where to specify password to connect to db

Please help me

Answer (score 7):

You looking for *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) scheme*, and the syntax is:

```
mysql://username:password@host:port/database/tablename
```

See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create-connection.html)